# Line break in Android adds padding

Tags: android, newline, textview

I have 5-10 lines of address information that I want to insert in a layout in my Android app.
I rather not use seperate textviews, but want to have **one** where I can insert line breaks manually.

I do this by adding \n and it seems to work, BUT.. This also adds padding or a space, I'm not sure which one.

Example:

This XML

```
<string name="contact_address">
    Street address\n
    City\n
    Country
</string>
```

Gives this output:

```
Street address
 City
 Country
```

Anyone know what could be wrong, or do I have to give up and make 5-10 seperate textviews?

Comment: what is the probelm in this Andreas. <string name="contact_address">Street address\nCity\nCountry</string>.It is working fine

Comment: Why do you have a string with all those inside?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try:

```
<string name="contact_address">Street address\nCity\nCountry</string>
```

to get rid of the spaces you are putting into your XML.

Comment: Thank you, it worked. Maybe I shouldn't have tried to make the XML look good with new rows for each word :)

Comment: @Andreas: Most of your resource XML won't have to worry about this, but the contents of string resources are sensitive to whitespace.

Answer (score 4):

I stumbled upon this and figured out a better way to keep the XML formatting and the line breaks without additional padding.

Use

```
<string>Line 1
      \nLine 2
      \nLine 3
</string>
```

Instead of

```
<string>Line 1\n
        Line 2\n
        Line 3
</string>
```